# alter image field from views

Tags: views

I have a content type called *Image*, it has 2 fields: a *image* field and a *copyright* field (with value *yes* or *no*).

I've created a view to display them a list. I have a requirement that if a user isn't logged in to our site (anonymous) and the value of *copyright* field is *yes*, the images in the view should have a mask added to them by default.

If user is logged in (authenticated), the images should be displayed normally.

Please tell me how can I do this?